# Ajax and SQL population of a dropdown

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, drop-down-menu

This seems to be the pain of my life I have now spent hours on this and none of the researched solutions seem to fix it. My code is supposed to populate a dropdown from a database called "notes" the field that is populated from is supposed is "name" and then the program is supposed to select all of the records with the name as the same selected. Except it does not seem to populate the list. I don't think that it's a database connection error as when all patients is selected all the records show up.

Here's my code:

```html
<?php

// php select option value from database

$hostname = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$databaseName = "CareM_database";

// connect to mysql database
   
 //load_data_select.php

 mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);  
 $connect = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $databaseName);  
 function fill_name($connect)  
 {  
      $output = '';  
      $sql = "SELECT name, id FROM name";  
      $result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);  
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
      {  
           $output .= '<option value="'.$row["id"].'">'.$row["name"].'</option>';  
      }  
      return $output;  
 }  
 function fill_patients($connect)  
 {  
      $output = '';  
      $sql = "SELECT * FROM notes";  
      $result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);  
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
      {  
           $output .= '<div class="col-md-3">';  
           $output .= '<div style="border:1px solid #ccc; padding:20px; margin-bottom:20px;">'.$row["details"].'';  
           $output .=     '</div>';  
           $output .=     '</div>';  
      }  
      return $output;  
 }  
 ?>  
 <!DOCTYPE html>  
 <html>  
      <head>  
           <title>Patient Notes View</title>  
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />  
           <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  
           <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>  
      </head>  
      <body>  
           <br /><br />  
           <div class="container">  
                <h3>  
                     <select name="name" id="name">  
                          <option value="">Show All Patients</option>  
                          <?php echo fill_patients($connect); ?>  
                     </select>  
                     <br /><br />  
                     <div class="row" id="show_patients">  
                          <?php echo fill_patients($connect);?>  
                     </div>  
                </h3>  
           </div>  
      </body>  
 </html>  
 <script>  
 $(document).ready(function(){  
      $('#name').change(function(){  
           var name_id = $(this).val();  
           $.ajax({  
                url:"load_data.php",  
                method:"POST",  
                data:{id:id},  
                success:function(data){  
                     $('#show_name').html(data);  
                }  
           });  
      });  
 });  
 </script>
```

Comment: There is a few wrong things in the code, e.g. data:{id:id} should be {id: name_id} and is your code file load_data.php or load_data_select.php?. Also, you call twice fill_patients, and it looks like there is no filter based on the patient id in your fill_patients method. Fire up your browser's debugger and see what is returned by the ajax call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not calling `fill_name` function in your `select`, but calling `fill_patients` instead, And I don't see any element with the id of `#show_name` in your html.

```html
<?php

// php select option value from database

$hostname = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$databaseName = "CareM_database";

// connect to mysql database
   
 //load_data_select.php

 mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);  
 $connect = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $databaseName);  
 function fill_name($connect)  
 {  
      $output = '';  
      $sql = "SELECT name, id FROM name";  
      $result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);  
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
      {  
           $output .= '<option value="'.$row["id"].'">'.$row["name"].'</option>';  
      }  
      return $output;  
 }  
 function fill_patients($connect)  
 {  
      $output = '';  
      $sql = "SELECT * FROM notes";  
      $result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);  
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
      {  
           $output .= '<div class="col-md-3">';  
           $output .= '<div style="border:1px solid #ccc; padding:20px; margin-bottom:20px;">'.$row["details"].'';  
           $output .=     '</div>';  
           $output .=     '</div>';  
      }  
      return $output;  
 }  
 ?>  
 <!DOCTYPE html>  
 <html>  
      <head>  
           <title>Patient Notes View</title>  
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />  
           </script>  
      </head>  
      <body>  
           <br /><br />  
           <div class="container">  
                <h3>  
                     <select name="name" id="name">  
                          <option value="">Show All Patients</option>  
                          <!-- <?php echo fill_patients($connect); ?> --> 
                          <!-- call fill_name function instead of the above function -->
                           <?php echo fill_name($connect); ?> 
                     </select>  
                     <br /><br />  
                     <div class="row" id="show_patients">  
                          <?php echo fill_patients($connect);?>  
                     </div>  
                </h3>  
           </div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function(){  
      $('#name').change(function(){  
           var name_id = $(this).val();  
           $.ajax({  
                url:"load_data.php",  
                method:"POST",  
                data:{id: name_id},
                success:function(data){  
                     $('#show_name').html(data);  
                }  
           });  
      });  
 });  
 </script>    
      </body>  
 </html>
```

Results[image]

Comment: you are using undeclared variable `id` in your `ajax` call instead of `name_id`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all add jquery.min.js before add bootstrap js

Comment: That hasn't changed anything

Comment: You need to change to separate yours views from your logic to separate your concerns and make your code more readable. I suggest any MVC framework like codeigniter

Comment: Please add Firebug extention into your mozila browser and debug your script using F+12 and you will check your request / response parameters inside it.